# Is it possible to style angular-xeditable?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two angular-xeditable styling questions:

1. How do I change the look of the editable text so it isn't blue and isn't underlined?
2. Is it possible to make the editable-text to extend a Bootstrap column?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Of course, overwrite it's `css`.

Answer (score 0):

Place below code and try.

```
.editable-input.editable-has-buttons { 
    height: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know...

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable"]);

app.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    name: 'awesome user'
  };
});
```

Here is the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/25/